# Removing array object according to its property in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a custom array like this and I want to delete the element where Student id is 4

```
var strNames = [Student(id: 1, name: "ghj"), Student(id: 4, name: "def"), Student(id: 9, name: "bkl")]
```

In classic way I do like this. Can anybody please help me mapping in Swift way?

```
 var sArray2: [Student] = []
    for item in strNames {
        if item.id != 4 {
            sArray2.append(Student(id: item.id, name: item.name))
        }
    }
strNames = sArray2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RangeReplaceableCollection` mutating method:

```
mutating func removeAll(where shouldBeRemoved: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows
```

---

In your case:

```
strNames.removeAll { $0.id == 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter function to filter out based on a condition, but filter function returns a new array with the filtered values

`var filteredArray = strNames.filter { (eachVal) -> Bool in eachVal.id != 4 }`